# How can i update post with old tags and new tags in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, tags

When I want to edit the post with the post's existing tags it only shows one tag though there are more tags in the selected post. I also want to input new tags in the post-editing blade.

**Post creating code**

```
           //Store Post
            public function storeNewPost(Request $request){
                //return $request->all();
                $request->validate([
                    'post_title' => 'required',
                    'post_details' => 'required',
                    'category_id' => 'required',
                    'image' => 'image|max:15360|dimensions:max_width=4000,max_height=3000'
                ]);

                $image = $request->file('post_thumbnail');
                
                $name_gen=uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Image::make($image)->resize(700,400)->save('frontend/assets/images/post/'.$name_gen);
                $save_url = 'frontend/assets/images/post/'.$name_gen;

                $post = Post::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'post_uper_title' =>$request->post_uper_title,
                    'post_title' =>$request->post_title,
                    'post_sub_title' =>$request->post_sub_title,
                    'post_details' =>$request->post_details,
                    'post_slug' =>str_replace(' ', '-', $request->post_title),
                    'seo_title' =>$request->seo_title,
                    'seo_descp' =>$request->seo_descp,
                    'lead' =>$request->lead,
                    'lead2' =>$request->lead2,
                    'featured' =>$request->featured,
                    'repoter_name' =>$request->repoter_name,
                    'division_id' =>$request->division_id,
                    'district_id' =>$request->district_id,
                    'category_id' =>$request->category_id,
                    'post_thumbnail' =>$save_url,
                    'thumbnail_caption' =>$request->thumbnail_caption,
                    'thumbnail_alt' =>$request->thumbnail_alt,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                ]);
                

                if($post){
                    $tags = explode(",", implode($request->tags));
                    $tagNames = [];
                    if (!empty($tags)) {
                        foreach ($tags as $tagName)
                        {
                        $tag = Tags::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tagName]);
                        if($tag)
                        {
                            $tagNames[] = $tag->id;
                        }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    $post->tags()->sync($tagNames);
                    $notification = array(
                        'message' => 'Post Inserted Successfully',
                        'alert-type' => 'success'
                    );
                    return redirect()->route('all.posts')->with($notification);
                }else{
                    return back();
                }
                

            }//end insert post
```

** post update code in post controller **

```
        //Edit Post
        public function editPost($news_id){
            $editPost = Post::findOrFail($news_id);
            $postDivisions = Division::get();
            $postCats = Category::get();
            $post_dist = District::get();
            $post_tags = Tags::all();
            return view('admin.post.edit-post', compact('postDivisions', 'postCats', 'editPost', 'post_dist', 'post_tags'));
        }

        //Update Post
        public function updatePost(Request $request){
            $news_id = $request->id;
        
            $image = $request->file('post_thumbnail');
                    
            $oldimage = $request->oldimage;
            
        if ($image) {
            $name_gen=hexdec(uniqid()).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->resize(700,400)->save('frontend/assets/images/post/'.$name_gen);
            $save_url = 'frontend/assets/images/post/'.$name_gen;
            if($oldimage){
                unlink($oldimage);
            }
            Post::findOrFail($news_id)->update([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'post_uper_title' =>$request->post_uper_title,
                'post_title' =>$request->post_title,
                'post_sub_title' =>$request->post_sub_title,
                'post_details' =>$request->post_details,
                'post_tags' =>$request->post_tags,
                'post_slug' =>$request->post_slug,
                'seo_title' =>$request->seo_title,
                'seo_descp' =>$request->seo_descp,
                'lead' =>$request->lead,
                'lead2' =>$request->lead2,
                'featured' =>$request->featured,
                'repoter_name' =>$request->repoter_name,
                'division_id' =>$request->division_id,
                'district_id' =>$request->district_id,
                'category_id' =>$request->category_id,
                'post_thumbnail' =>$save_url,
                'thumbnail_caption' =>$request->thumbnail_caption,
                'thumbnail_alt' =>$request->thumbnail_alt,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Post Updated Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
        
            return redirect()->route('all.posts')->with($notification);
        }else{
            Post::findOrFail($news_id)->update([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'post_uper_title' =>$request->post_uper_title,
                'post_title' =>$request->post_title,
                'post_sub_title' =>$request->post_sub_title,
                'post_details' =>$request->post_details,
                'post_tags' =>$request->post_tags,
                'post_slug' =>$request->post_slug,
                'seo_title' =>$request->seo_title,
                'seo_descp' =>$request->seo_descp,
                'lead' =>$request->lead,
                'lead2' =>$request->lead2,
                'featured' =>$request->featured,
                'repoter_name' =>$request->repoter_name,
                'division_id' =>$request->division_id,
                'district_id' =>$request->district_id,
                'category_id' =>$request->category_id,
                'post_thumbnail' =>$oldimage,
                'thumbnail_caption' =>$request->thumbnail_caption,
                'thumbnail_alt' =>$request->thumbnail_alt,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        
            $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Post Updated Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
        
            return redirect()->route('all.posts')->with($notification);
        }
        }//end update post
```

** post editing blade's tags code **

```html
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-label">{{__('Post Tags')}}</label>
                                                    
             <input type="text" class="w-100" id="tagnames" name="tags[]" data-role="tagsinput" 
             @foreach ($editPost->tags as $tags) value="{{$tags->name}}" @endforeach>
                                                    
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // try this 
 <input type="text" class="w-100" id="tagnames" name="tags[]" data-role="tagsinput"  value="@foreach($editPost->tags as $tags){{$tags->name.','}}@endforeach">
```

Comment: Thanks, Mostafa Hana, Your code is working well that i wanted. Thank you so much for your time being.

Answer (score 0):

If you have manyToMany relation in your models use `sync()` method on update method.

Example:
`$post->tags()->sync($request->tags);`